# não estou conseguindo juntar dados - deve ser falta de INNER JOIN

Tags: join, tabela-html, inner

Tenho duas tabelas, a `tab_prefixo` apresenta número de `prefixo` e `gerente` responsável (dados importantes), e na outra (tabela `tab_valores`), também apresenta o `prefixo`, mais `nome`, `valor` e `data`.

Quero que, com comando `prefixo.movefirst`, ele pegue o primeiro `prefixo` da tabela `tab_prefixo` e procure, na tabela `tab_valores`, as linhas que possuem o mesmo `valor` `prefixo` e copie aqueles dados para uma nova tabela, a tabela `tab_correio`, que vai constar `prefixo`, `nome`, `valor`, `data` e `gerente`, e encaminhe correio para tal prefixo. Após, com comando `prefixo.movenext`, ele passe para o segundo `prefixo` da tabela `tab_prefixo` e, novamente, procure os dados que contenham o mesmo `prefixo` na tabela `tab_valores` e copie os dados requeridos na tabela `tab_correio`, e mande correio para tal prefixo.. e assim sucessivamente.

Estou conseguindo fazer uma consulta apenas, com os comando abaixo:

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim Linha As Integer

Set prefixo = db.OpenRecordset("select * from Tab_prefixo order by prefixo")
Set valores = db.OpenRecordset("select * from tab_valores")
Set correio = db.OpenRecordset("tab_correio")

prefixo.MoveFirst
Do While Not prefixo.EOF

   If agencias!CODPREF = divida!agencia Then

   correio.AddNew
   correio!prefixo = divida!prefixo
   correio!nome = divida!nome
   correio!valor = divida!valor
   correio!Data = divida!Data
   correio!GERENTE = agencias!GERENTE
   correio.Update

   End If

   agencias.MoveNext
Loop

   'CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM tab_correio"

End Sub
```

Na verdade sei que meu comando está incompleto.. falta algo, e deve ter algo fora do lugar, mas empaquei aqui.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço muito, pois não estou conseguindo seguir adiante.. de repente falta até um `inner join`, estou tentando de tudo, mas não está andando..

Answer (score 0):

Levando em consideração que o prefixo é único entra as tabelas.
E que as tabelas estão criadas com os campos que você informou, basicamente isso já resolveria seu problema.

```
insert into tab_correio
select Tprx.prefixo, Tval.nome, Tval.valor, Tval.data,Tprx.gerente from tab_prefixo  Tprx
inner join tab_valores Tval
on (Tprx.prefixo = Tval.prefixo)
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda amigo!
mas onde, exatamente, coloco esse comando? ao colocar no access 2013 fica em vermelho e o programa não entende